# How to show unique content to a non logged in user?

Tags: php, algorithm, session

I am creating a site where I need to show random snippets to the user which keep changing every few seconds. The snippet database itself will be pretty huge. What I am thinking about is the best way to show them a snippet without it duplicating.

So my query would be like:

```
$random = '<value between 1 and row_count of table>';
$query = `select snippet from table limit $random,1`;
```

Then I show that snippet to the user. This will work pretty ok, but how can I make sure the user does not see the same snippet again during his visit? Also, there is no login, so I cannot associate snippet with a user id.

I thought I will store snippet ID in session and exclude it from next query. But I am not sure if that is the best way to do this. Are there other solutions out there?

Any suggestions? I am developing using LAMP which is why I have added the tags that I have. And I know I have not posted any code..

Comment: Even if you've not posted code, you've posted your plans, your considerations AND the fact that they're sub-optimal. If everybody would behave like you, SO would be a better place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this solution uses cookies.

1. When the user "loads" a snippet, store the snippet ID in a cookie.
2. To load the next snippet, search for the cookie's value, and use it to generate a new snippet id. (tip: use the current id (i suppose it's a number) as the seed for the RNG) If there is no cookie, it's the first visit then pick a random number.
3. go to #1

If you set the cookie lifespan as relatively short, you'll be quite sure that the user won't get stuck in a predetermined sequence.

The other solutions (derivations of the `NOT IN` keyword or approach) does not scale well when the user looks at a lot of snippets in the same session... And you should plan for long sessions, i hope... Stumbleupon.com is a nice example of long addictive session which fetch a lot of distinct pages. It's similar to your idea.

Good luck!

EDIT: thinking again about this algorithm, i found a flaw: if the random ID obtained with the previous ID as a seed gives a number which has already been used, the user is now in a loop (example: `#A generates #B which generates #C. If #C generates #A or #B the user is in a loop`).

Therefore, if your user finds a duplicate, you may add a link called "signal duplicate" which simply drops the cookie and generates a new random ID. This new approach has 2 pros:

1. Gives the guest user the illusion that he can actually control the workflow, and even interact with it
2. Solves the loop bug explained above.

Comment: thats a good solution to explore. The only concern I have is that if the user hits the row_count threshold, we will need to restart from a lower number, and then there is a possibility of duplicates right? but very good suggestion to think about. +1!

Comment: @open_sourse well, I don't see that as an issue, since you said that you'll have a "pretty huge" database. Also, you're working with non-logged users, if they want a better service they can always register, right? ;) Anyway, the random numbers aren't always increasing, but jumping up and down the rows, so there's no "row_count reached" problem, imho

Comment: Moreover, if i just get a duplicate even in Stumbleupon, i just click to get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Storing in the session would be fine if you only worry about the users current visit.  If you want something more permanent you could use cookies.

To get the random snippet you could do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table where id not in (snippets, from, session) ORDER BY RAND() ASC limit 1
```

Obviously I'm making an assumption that you would store the ID's of snippets in the session

Also note that "NOT IN" or "IN" for that matter, are not the most performant solutions, but this should work to get a proof of concept going

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes at the moment I am thinking of storing id's of snippets. Just that I am worried if it will become too big..

Comment: I believe (although please dont quote me) that the cookie is size limit is about 4k. Session is much larger. You should be able to get alot of id's in there, if that's all you're storing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
SELECT snippet FROM snippets ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the snippet ID in cookies as array() (i.e) it should have all the seen ID's and while getting new one you should get all the ID from that cookie array variable and query as **NOT IN (ID's from cookie array)**